# Percorrendo um arquivo de constantes

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

Criei o seguinte arquivo de constantes (constantes.ts):

```
export const USER_INFO = 'user-info';
export const USER_SEARCH = 'user-search';
export const USER = 'user';
```

Este arquivo é utilizado para setar, obter e excluir arquivos do localStorage:

```
import { USER_INFO } from '../utils/constantes';
const usuarioLogado = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(USER_INFO));
```

Preciso percorrer o arquivo para utilizar todas as contantes em uma linha de código, porém não sei como realiza-lo, pois o foreach não é suportado nessa situação. Como fazer?

Segue abaixo um exemplo prático do que eu queria realizar:

```
import * as CONSTANTES_CACHE from '../utils/constantes';

export class CacheService {

  constructor() { }

  limparCache(): void {    
    CONSTANTES_CACHE.forEach(x => {
      localStorage.removeItem(x);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser uma maneira simples de fazer isto é ao invés de utilizar várias constantes, deixar tudo em uma só dentro de um **array** e fazer um `for` para percorrer os dados:

```js
const USER = ['user_info', 'user-search', 'user'];

for(let i = 0; i<USER.length; i++) {
 console.log('localStorage.removeItem ' + (USER[i]));
}
```

Comment: Boa ideia. Eu implementei daquela forma, pois vários arquivos da minha aplicação importam apenas a constante desejada e no meu arquivo de constantes existem muito mais do que aquelas 3 que eu citei de exemplo.

Comment: Eu consegui implementar da seguinte maneira: 

limparCache(): void {
    Object.keys(CONSTANTES_CACHE).forEach(x => {
      localStorage.removeItem(x);
    });
  }

Valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score -1):

Eu consegui implementar da seguinte maneira:
limparCache(): void {
Object.keys(CONSTANTES_CACHE).forEach(x => {
localStorage.removeItem(x);
});
}